# Wrap bash script call with connect / disconnect from VPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, bash

Once or twice a day, when the service I'm building is in production I'll have to read a database that sits behind a VPN.

Now, in the development phase I've been doing as follows. As `root` user I run:

```
openfortivpn -c /etc/openfortivpn/config
```

Then, as `web` user I run:

```
sh manage.sh sync_master
```

Where `manage.sh` is:

```
. /web/.env;. /web/bin/activate;/web/bin/python /web/src/manage.py $1 $2 $3
```

After the synchronisation happens, I go back to `root` user and on the `screen` I left the VPN connection open, I stop it using `ctrl+c`.

Now I need to run this from crontab. So my question is twofold: Is this a good way of doing this? How can I put all this logic in a bash script?

Thanks!

PS: Running on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Simply start the VPN as a service at boot and keep it up and running rather than starting and stopping every time as that seem rather fragile.

Comment: That's one of the many reasons why we don't run long running services in `screen`. As several people have said, make an actual service of it.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest to write a systemd.service that starts|stops the VPN and use `systemctl` within the script.

Comment: Indeed, this turned out to be a very easy to implement and to reason about. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Your welcome. Good to read that you managed implementing the solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to start/stop/restart a process in linux would be to track it by a PID file. Here is an example script you can start with. A good thing is that below script also have a varify sections, so you can put it in cron like `"/path/to/scriptname varify"` and it will start openvpn if it is not running.

```
#!/bin/bash

DAEMON_PATH="/full/path/to/"
DAEMON="/full/path/to/openfortivpn"
DAEMONOPTS="-c /etc/openfortivpn/config"

NAME=openfortivpn
DESC="openfortivpn"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

case "$1" in
start)
        printf "%-50s" "Starting $NAME... "
        echo  "Starting $NAME... " 
        cd $DAEMON_PATH
        PID=`$DAEMON $DAEMONOPTS & echo $!`
        echo "Saving PID" $PID " to " $PIDFILE
        if [ -z $PID ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "Fail"
        else
            echo $PID > $PIDFILE
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
        fi
;;
status)
        printf "%-50s" "Checking $NAME..."
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            if [ -z "`ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
                printf "%s\n" "Process dead but pidfile exists"
            else
                echo "Running"
            fi
        else
            printf "%s\n" "Service not running"
        fi
;;
stop)
        printf "%-50s" "Stopping $NAME"
        echo "Stopping $NAME" 
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            cd $DAEMON_PATH
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            kill -HUP $PID
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
            rm -f $PIDFILE
        else
            printf "%s\n" "pidfile not found"
            pkill -f "openfortivpn"
        fi
;;
varify)
        printf "%-50s" "Checking $NAME..."
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            if [ -z "`ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
                printf "%s\n" "Process dead but pidfile exists"
                echo "restarting..."
                $0 restart
            else
                echo "Running"
            fi
        else
            printf "%s\n" "Service not running"
            echo "starting..."
            $0 restart
        fi
;;

restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
;;

*)
        echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop|restart|varify}"
        exit 1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the response, but I gotta say, I felt a little overwhelmed with your response. I was looking for somethings simpler...